# prioritise Async task over web view

Tags: android-studio, webview, android-asynctask

My android application has web-view and control buttons, web view streams live video from raspberry pi camera and on button press the traction commands(on,off,right,left) goes to the redis-DB on the same raspberry-pi

my observations is when web view streams video the control commands on button pressed reach pi at very slow speed

my priority is control first and then streaming how to accomplish the same?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.190:8000");
    Log.e("aaa","Streaming video");
}
//on button clicked

public void StartTraction(View view) {
    MyAsyncTaskStart myAsyncTasks = new MyAsyncTaskStart();
    myAsyncTasks.execute();

}

public class  MyAsyncTaskStart extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            Jedis jedis = new Jedis("192.168.0.190", 6379);
            jedis.set("motorKey","ON");
            jedis.disconnect();
        } catch (JedisConnectionException e) {

        } catch (NullPointerException e1) {

        } catch (Exception e1) {

        }
        return "";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    }
}

}
```

Comment: I think the speed depends on your phone ram and network connection now. device model?

Comment: Lenovo TAB 10(TB-X304L)

Comment: yep, its quite a challenge for 2gb ram and chipset. try monitor your profiler. View > Tool Windows > profiler